# Login Form for accessing SQL server data base error

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I've been trying  to make a login form to my database for a mobile shop store (university project). I have an Employee table containing Emp_name and Emp_password as id and password to then access the  database. This is the code but somehow I created the design and when I click on the log in button it doesn't write any message for me. Please tell me how to let this login form launch the database separately of mysql server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.OleDb; 
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace login_form
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    public Form1()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=RAYMOND-PC;Initial Catalog=[mobile shop   final];Integrated Security=True";

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sTUDENTDataSet.login' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.  
        //this.loginTableAdapter.Fill(this.sTUDENTDataSet.login);  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=RAYMOND-PC;Initial Catalog= mobile shop final;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        {
        }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=RAYMOND-PC;Initial Catalog=mobile shop final;Integrated Security=True";  
            con.Open();
            string Emp_name=textBox1.Text;
            string Emp_password = textBox2.Text ;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Emp_name , Emp_password from Employee where Emp_name='" + textBox1.Text + "'and Emp_password='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);  
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (Emp_name == textBox1.Text && Emp_password==textBox2.Text)
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Login sucess Welcome to Mobile shop");  
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mobile shop final");  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login please check username and password");  
            }  
            con.Close();  
        }

    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();

    }

    private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you ever debug your code? Did you check your all values are correct? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And don't store your passwords as a plain text. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database Don't forget to use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and objects.

Comment: @SonerGönül  yes i debug it and when i  enter the  emp name  and password nothing happened notting i added a connection by clicking  on  connect to data  base in tools  and  added the tables  in the data bindings of the  maing login form

Comment: @SonerGönül  i'm still a beginner like i'm still learning c++ and data structures algorithms and oop but i'm trying to do this for my extra knowledge so can you please explain in details :D?

Comment: remove `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();` from everywhere in the code except in the button1 click event and remove the connection string also; to restate, remove all your code except in button 1 and button 2 from your project form. You're opening up connections for no reason and not closing them.

Comment: but that won't help my code to connect  any  way so it's doesn't make  a  big  problem i just  want  it  to  run ... any  ideas ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Use `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` to create connection string and `PropertyGrid` control to enter values. This will guarantee that every option is correct.

Comment: would you please explaining with code details ? cause  i'm still  beginner :D??

Comment: Instead of simple string assignment like "Data Source=...", define `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` object and use it for connection string: `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mcs = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()`. To get the real connection string use `mcs.ConnectionString` property. Put a `PropertyGrid` control in your form and assign its `SelectedObject` to `mcs`. This will be editor for all possible MySQL connection options. Note: `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` requires reference to `MySql.Data`.